# Sort vector of objects by value of member

Tags: c++

I have a class Group with member vector of objects of class Student.
Each Student has a member int coef.
I need to sort Students in vector by descending of their coefs.
coef is private member, so I use function:

```
unsigned int getCoef() const { return this->coef; }
```

I'm going by this example: https://www.walletfox.com/course/sortvectorofcustomobjects.php
But when I reload operator <, I have an error Too many parameters.
My overloaded operator:

```
bool operator<(const Group& s1, const Group& s2)
    {
        return s1.getCoef() < s2.getCoef();
    }
```

So, maybe it is other ways to compare by coef?

Comment: Did you implement `operator<` as a class method or a free function? As written in your post, that should be a free function outside your class.

Comment: You could just pass a lambda to [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) - it's less awkward than overloading `operator<` globally. Anyway, you haven't shown either the (minimal) [complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or the literal error message, which is why the existing answer had to provide two contingent solutions.

Comment: @françois-andrieux you marked my question by dublicate randomly? It is not about that!

Comment: @vchkhr2 It seems like an exact duplicate to me. If you disagree, please share why you don't think so. I certainly don't close questions randomly.